# View multiline code chunks when browsing command history

Tags: command-history, r

I do datascience an use R frequently.  The way that probably 99% of R users interact with R is RStudio, an IDE with a lot of great features.  I'm increasingly working in the cloud, so Im trying to recreate a lot of the great features of RStudio with a more lightweight, terminal-ready `vim`+`tmux` setup.

One feature of RStudio is that after you send a chunk of code to the R console, when browsing the command history, you see the entire chunk.  When using R in a unix terminal, however, you just get the last line.

How can I configure the R console to show entire chunks when browsing command history?

As an example, lets say I run the following code chunk in RStudio and in an R console in a unix terminal:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl)
```

If I press the up arrow in Rstudio, I get:

```
> library(dplyr)

  mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, cyl)
```

However, if I press the up arrow in an R console in a unix terminal, I get:

```
> select(mpg, cyl)
```

Is there any way I can make the R console behave like RStudio?

Comment: radian: A 21 century R console https://github.com/randy3k/radian